# find and -exec with multiple parameters

Tags: performance, find

I have a command to encrypt (codecrypt) files like this example:

```
ccr -aer john -R file.txt > file.txt.ccr
```

I'd like to do a loop with several files, so I came up with this:

```
for a in *.txt; do ccr -aer john -R "$a" > "$a".ccr; done
```

I'd like to know how can I do the same approach using `find`, and if there is any performance advantage between `find` and `for`.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the `for` loop would be faster as `find` will not only look for files in the current directory but recurse any sub-directories.  And `for` is a built-in shell command, where `find` is a separate program.